# Jekyll - highlight current page nav link using permalinks

Tags: navigation, jekyll

I just started using jekyll and can't seem to figure out how to highlight the navigation link for the current page, using permalinks. It works when not using permalinks but can't figure how to make permalinks work.

***_data/navigation.yml***

```
- name: Home
  link: /
- name: About
  link: /about
- name: Blog
  link: /blog
```

***_includes/header.html***

```
  <nav>
    {% for item in site.data.navigation %}
      <a href="{{ item.link }}" {% if page.url == item.link %}class="current"{% endif %}>{{ item.name | upcase }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <nav>
    {% assign current = page.url | downcase | split: '.' %}
    {% for item in site.data.navigation %}
      <a href="{{ item.link }}" {% if current[0] == item.link %}class="current"{% endif %}>{{ item.name | upcase }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me, as per Pierce Darragh stated in his [gist](https://gist.github.com/pdarragh/c7ca120604c1a1d8b8de):

```html
<!-- This finds the current page so it can be highlighted. -->

{% for entry in site.data.navigation %}
{% capture fullurl %}{{ site.baseurl }}{{ entry.url }}{% endcapture %}
    {% if fullurl == page.url %}
        {% assign current_page = fullurl %}
        {% break %}
    {% elsif page.url contains fullurl %}
        {% assign current_page = fullurl %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<!-- Then we build the nav bar. -->
<nav>
    <ul>
    {% for entry in site.data.navigation %}
        {% if entry.url == current_page %}
            {% assign current = ' class="current"' %}
        {% else %}
            <!-- We have to declare it 'null' to ensure it doesn't propagate. -->
            {% assign current = null %}
        {% endif %}
        {% assign sublinks = entry.sublinks %}
        {% if sublinks %}
        <li{{ current }}>
            <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
            <ul>
                {% for sublink in sublinks %}
                <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ sublink.url }}">{{ sublink.title }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li{{ current }}><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```